# Google Commerce Search for a standalone app?

Tags: google-product-search

I am building a mobile app.
I am not merchant, I am just an app developer.
I want to integrate some of google's search abilities, and so I have stumbled upon Google Commerce Search. Its features seem to cover the exact features I am looking for.
However, it seems as though it's only meant for retailers, and the pricing is accordingly.

So my questions are:

- Is there any way to integrate Google's product or commerce search through an publicly open
  api?
- Is there any way to integrate some image search as well (find similar images)?

Thank you.

Comment: i would like to integrate it in magento store but need a helping hand on it.

Comment: @vondip: Is there any progress over this? I also want to create a mobile app which will have list of products from google. Merchant account is mandatory for GCS.